# when I extrude Edges, It creates new edges

Tags: extrude

when I extrude Edges, It creates new edges.

EX.[image]

BUT I want like this
[image]

what should i do when i want like 2nd piture.

Comment: That is what the extrude tool is supposed to do, but I’m glad you added that last bit and the screenGIFs. It made it very clear what you wanted and what was happening unexpectedly.

Answer (score 1):

You just move the edges. You can press G, you can click the Move icon in the toolbar on the left of the 3D viewport to bring up the moving gizmo, etc.